# NSFetchedResultsController W/ Custom Table Cell Incompatible Pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been trying to get a grip on CoreData. After several attempts to find a good tutorial on it I made a lot of progress with a [tutorial on youtube](http://youtu.be/G36_91H4CKE). However when I got to the `NSFetchedResultsController` I'm getting a warning on my custom table cell `ITDContactCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` stating that it's an incompatible pointer initializing with `UITableViewCell` (the tutorial does not use custom cells).

Even worse, when I attempt to add an item I get this nice ugly error.

> 2013-12-04 19:15:48.407 Ping[490:60b] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1138 2013-12-04
>   19:15:48.409 Ping[490:60b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.
>   An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo
>   (null)

I've spent hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I can't wrap my head around it. So if anyone can take a gander at my code and give me suggestions on how I can fix it I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Controller:

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.ContactsListTableView;
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            Contact *changeContact = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            ITDContactCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", changeContact.contactFirstName, changeContact.contactLastName];
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: My implementation of number of rows and sections.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

`fetchedResultsController` is defined in the interface simply as `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController`

Comment: Share your implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Also you have two totally different issues so maybe consider making them separate questions.

Comment: Have you implement `-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` ?

Comment: I edited my original post to include those. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is referring to the fact that the method

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

returns a UITableViewCell, which is not literally your ITDContactCell. Placing a cast before the method should remove the warning.

```
ITDContactCell *cell = (ITDContactCell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The other error is probably because of some lack of relationship between your fetchedResultsController and your tableView. Showing your tableView delegate and source methods would help. I assume you have already implemented something similar:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return _fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ITDContactCell *cell = (ITDContactCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // assign cell content

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if(_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return  _fetchedResultsController;
}

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.ContactsListTableView;
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            Contact *changeContact = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            ITDContactCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", changeContact.contactFirstName, changeContact.contactLastName];
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

As a note, you should not be using the reloadData method in your tableview, since the table is reloaded (via the fetched results controller) after saving changes to your NSManagedObjectContext.

**EDIT 2:**

Is you NSManagedObjectContext nil?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm currently combing through your implementation vs mine to see if I can spot any differences that will correct the issue. I did get rid of the warning with what you said though, but still getting the ugly error. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: I'm trying to check if NSManagedObjectContext is nil but I don't know how to write it to an NSLog to do so. Every time I try my app crashes with uncaught exception.

Comment: No, it's not nil. I just did a simple if check

Comment: Stupid mistake, I forgot to reassign my delegates after changing some code. So it had nothing to do with the controller after all. This will still help a lot of other people so I'm marking it as the right answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad things worked out for you and the answer at least verified that your NSFetchedResultsController was in order. Thanks for remembering to come back and choose an answer as well.